# Invoking a parent's class from child class with no hardcoded arguments

Tags: python, oop

I'm fairly new to Python and I've been struggling with inheritance concepts on a work project. The base class would get directory paths, table names etc from a config file (I'm keeping mosthis out because it's irrelevant to the question below) and pass this to a Child class via super()__ init __.

The base class also has a method to export a dataframe to MS SQL Server. The problem is, I can't pass the pandas dataframe from my Child class to my Parent Class, only hardcoded values. Reason I'm doing this is because the dataframes are fairly different from one another (demanding unique data manipulation), but they all come from the same place and will be placed in the same database.

So pretty much I need to run SQL_Export from **Parent** with the dataframe defined in the **Child** as input. I tried placing SQLExport in my init, but I get

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

What I have:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pandas as pd

config_object = ConfigParser()
config_object.read('config.ini')

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, report, df, date=today):
        self.report = report
        self.df = df
        self.name = config_object[self.report]['name']
        self.table_name = config_object[self.report]['table_name']
   
    def SQLExport(self):
        return self.df.to_sql(self.table_name, con="engine")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('REPORTNAME', self.load_dataframe)
        super().SQLexport(self)

    def load_dataframe(self):
        self.df = pd.read_json(self.name + ".json")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Child()
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code

- `super().SQLexport(self)` function name is wrong in your client class(it should be `self.SQLExport`) and it wont accept any parameters so self is not required to pass
- `pd.read_json(self.name. +".json")` - `Child` class has no attribute `name`, so your self.name will fail
- self.load_dataframe function is being passed to super.**init** method instead of dataframe and no return statement(`return df`) in `load_dataframe` function in child class

the above issues are corrected and, you can try with below code which write the dataframe in sqlite in memory database

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

config_object = ConfigParser()
config_object.read('config.ini')


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, report, df):
        self.report = report
        self.df = df
        self.name = config_object[self.report]['name']
        self.table_name = config_object[self.report]['table_name']

    def SQLExport(self):
        print(self.table_name)
        return self.df.to_sql(self.table_name, con=engine)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="test_123"
        super().__init__('REPORTNAME', self.load_dataframe())
        super().SQLExport()

    def load_dataframe(self):
        self.df = pd.read_json(self.name + ".json")
        return self.df

    def read_data(self):
        print(engine.execute("SELECT * FROM sample_table").fetchall())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Child()
    x.read_data()
```

Comment: Thanks @nalanagula, I assumed  `super()__init__` would make `Child` inherit `Parent's` attributes automatically. I didn`t realize I had to reassign the variables again in the new class. It will solve this and an issue I had in another class. Cheers!